# Ubuntu Login bounce back

Tags: nvidia, login, lightdm, gdm

Disclaimer: I have tried the existing answers to various questions already. None of them worked.

**Problem:** 
When I Login to Ubuntu 14.04 via GUI, I'm redirected to the Login page again.

**Observations:**

- I'm able to Login via Terminal (using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)
- When I Login via GUI, I'm **not** getting any password mismatch errors. It just redirect me to Login screen again.
- I'm able to Login as a Guest in via GUI.
- Creating a new user and logging in under that one has the same problem.
- `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` is **not** found (only `users.conf` exist in `/etc/lightdm/`).
- Under `~/.cache/`, `sessions` is not there. (Identified while trying an answer from Ask Ubuntu)
- `linux-generic` is up to date.

**Background:**
I changed the Login Password as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password). I'm getting this problem after that.

**Things I tried:**

- Updating (`sudo apt-get update`)
- Removing `.Xauthority` file.
- Reinstalling **lightdm**.
- Installing **gdm** instead of **lightdm**.
- Reconfiguring the above **lightdm**.
- Changing the ownership of `.Xauthority`.
- Reinstalling `Nvidia`.
- Purging and Reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`.

When I tried reinstalling Nvidia,
I got this [image]
Kindly see more information about this [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3DtVn7J8-wYd3Zyc19heW9FTHM/view?usp=sharing).

Please Help me out.

Comment: I have a similar issue